# Unresolved function sass math.div() in WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2021.1.3 and receive a error that this function unresolved. Of course, this is just a warning from the WebStorm and I have no errors in execution.

[image]

Needless to say, I do not receive any errors for the following list.
[image]

I think this list needs to be updated. Also used the global Sass installation command but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51021#focus=Comments-27-4978592.0-0

This is fixed for next major 2021.2 version (you can try the EAP now if you wish: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/07/webstorm-2021-2-eap-6/)

For 2021.1 branch it will be available in 2021.1.4 (when it will be released, of course).